# Forcing a TCP stream to send buffer contents

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client

I am using Csharp tcp sockets to send data between a client and server.
Now the problem as i see it or as i perceive it is that tcp is a stream protocol and will not push (send) data unless their is a sufficient amount of it.

For instance say i wanted to send some data whatever it is doesnt matter lets just say its 8 bytes long. The behaviour i am seeing is no matter how long i wait it wont send that data unless i push more behind it presumably until i reach the tcp buffer.

So my question is. If i want to send a small amount of data via tcp do i need to append garbage to the end to force the socket to send. ( I wouldnt feel good about this ) or is their an alternative way i can force the front segment of the stream to send.

thanks in advance. i am still learning tcp so excuse the ignorance.

Comment: There are several ways to send data using sockets in .Net. Which one are you using, i.e. could you show us short excerpt of your code?

Comment: oh yeah i am using the TcpClient object and setting NoDelay = true on both client and server does not solve the problem.

Comment: I think it has less to do with not getting the data and more to do with me not using NetworkStream.Read properly. I will look more into the api documentation. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: "The behaviour i am seeing is no matter how long i wait it wont send that data unless i push more behind it presumably until i reach the tcp buffer." I find that part very surprising. It should send small data eventually, it just waits a bit to see if anything new arrives.

Comment: Show some code (of both the client and the server), it sounds like you're wrapping the stream in some other buffered streams, there's no problems sending 8 bytes with TCP , it should not wait "forever" once you've pushed the data down to TCP, only usually a small amount of time.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rSyLU06i here is the server

Comment: and the client http://pastebin.com/UrkEbPWd the first time i run the client i dont get the message the second time and every time after i start getting it which i find weird

Comment: i was getting socket errors. so the flaw was with the code i got from an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't set `NoDelay` unless you are an expert at TCP/IP and understand its full ramifications. If you haven't read Stevens, don't even think about it.

Here's an example question: if you establish a socket connection and send 8 bytes on it, are the 8 bytes immediately sent or does the Nagle algorithm wait for more data to send? The answer is "the 8 bytes are sent immediately" - but don't consider messing with Nagle until you understand exactly *why* that is the answer.

Here's another question: in a standard command/response protocol, how much Nagle delay is applied to each packet? The answer: none. Again, you should research *why* Nagle causes *no* delays in this common scenario.

If you're not seeing the data sent by 250 milliseconds (the maximum delay caused by Nagle in the worst possible scenario), then there is something else wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `NoDelay` property (I think it's what disables [Nagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)).